# Apache curl via HTTP proxy

Tags: php, proxy, curl, selinux

I am trying to get PHP to execute a curl connection to another server. To connect to the server, we need to go via a proxy. 
Within bash, we have set the env-variable http_proxy and this works correctly while using the php script from the command-line. However, when attempting to execute curl, or wget from apache, it fails with no errors.
The server is configured with SELinux based on Centos defaults. This has been unchanged as I am unsure about SELinux configuration.
Has anyone else had a similar issue?

Comment: Just to be clear: are you trying to eval/exec the curl binary from within a PHP file that's being served by apache?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under SELinux httpd (and therefore its children) isn't allowed to make outgoing connections. Try

`setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1`

You should see messages in `/var/log/messages` or `/var/log/audit/audit.log` if in fact selinux is the cause.

If you are new to running apache under selinux have a look at `httpd_selinux(8)`.

Edited to add: P.S. If you're not an selinux guru plan to spend a lot of time trying to get even mildly unusual apache configs working under selinux.

Comment: Yes it was SELinux that was preventing apache from performing the curl execution. However, after fixing that, I ended up disabling SELinux anyway because of the need to perform command execution which was also being blocked by SELinux. Thanks anyway and sorry for the late response.

Comment: is it possible to allow connection to localhost only ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you told curl it needs to connect via a proxy?

```
$curlHandle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.google.com');
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, true);
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 8080);
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'proxy.localnet.com');
// optional
// curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);
// curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, 'user:s3cr3t'); 
// curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_PROXYAUTH, CURLAUTH_NTLM);

$out=curl_exec($curlHandle);

curl_close($curlHandle);
```